# Is there any kind of exception to sum up two variables from functions in C#?

Tags: c#, static-variables

I am a very beginner in C#, and OOP also.

Here I am feeling an interesting matter while summing up two static variables from outer functions in C#.

Here is my code.

```
using System;

namespace StaticFun
{
    class StaticFun
    {
        public static int a;
        public static int b;

        public void count()
        {
            a++;
        }

        public void mount()
        {
            b++;
        }

        public static int getsum()
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            StaticFun obj = new StaticFun();

            obj.count();
            obj.count();
            obj.count();
            Console.WriteLine("Value of a for obj : {0}.", StaticFun.a);

            obj.mount();
            obj.mount();
            Console.WriteLine("\na = {0}\nb = {0}\nSum : {0}.", StaticFun.a, StaticFun.b, StaticFun.getsum());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

When I compiled this program, I get outputs like below.

> Value of a for obj : 3.
>
> a = 3
>
> b = 3
>
> Sum : 3

I can understand first two values from the output. But for b, it might be 2! Isn't it? In class StaticFun I made a function `public void mount()` to increment the value of b by 1. Since b being a static variable, its initial value was 0. Then after calling that function two times, it value would be 2. How the value can be 3, I can't understand that fact. Also, the sum might be 3+2=5, as my assumption. But it made the same value as the variable a and b as well.

I thought it happened for their static behavior. But astonishingly, it gave same output for non-static variable also!

Here is my Second code ,

```
using System;

namespace StaticFun
{
    class StaticFun
    {
        public int a;
        public int b;

        public void count()
        {
            a++;
        }

        public void mount()
        {
            b++;
        }

        public int getsum()
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            StaticFun obj = new StaticFun();

            obj.count();
            obj.count();
            obj.count();
            Console.WriteLine("Value of a for obj : {0}.", obj.a);

            obj.mount();
            obj.mount();
            Console.WriteLine("\na = {0}\nb = {0}\nSum : {0}.", obj.a, obj.b, obj.getsum());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And the output as well,

> Value of a for obj : 3.
>
> a = 3
>
> b = 3
>
> Sum : 3

I completely misunderstand this fact. Is there anyone to make my concepts clear about those outputs?

Answer (score 8):

The problem isn't your summing stuff - it's the way you print it:

```
Console.WriteLine("\na = {0}\nb = {0}\nSum : {0}.", StaticFun.a, StaticFun.b, StaticFun.getsum());
```

Your actually printing the same object three times in a row. You should increase the number in the brackets:

```
Console.WriteLine("\na = {0}\nb = {1}\nSum : {2}.", StaticFun.a, StaticFun.b, StaticFun.getsum());
```

For more information about string formatting read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

By the way, I'd suggest using string interpolation - it'd work like that:

```
Console.WriteLine($"\na = {StaticFun.a}\nb = {StaticFun.b}\nSum : {StaticFun.getsum()}.");
```

If you want to know more about string interpolation, take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx.

Comment: @ShahShishir - FYI, the C# convention is for method names to begin with an upper case letter.

Comment: How does String interpolation work here ?

Can you give some reference? :)

Comment: @ShahShishir I added a reference to my answer.

Comment: That was great for me indeed !!! But it gives Compilation error on Visual Studio 2013, but compiles successfully on http://ideone.com ... Is there any way to make VS compiler friendly to compile source codes while using string interpolation ??? :)

Comment: Maybe you didn't configure the .Net version correctly.

Answer (score 3):

don't discount this either since its part of C# 6 and higher now too

`Console.WriteLine($"\na = {StaticFun.a}\nb = {StaticFun.b}\nSum : {StaticFun.getsum()}.");`